# Should I resize UIImage before rendering to screen?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, render

When developing an ios app, let's say I have large size UIImage

```
let image = UIImage(named: "unicorn")! // actual image size is 2000x2000
```

Should I resize before rendering to screen

```
let size = CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
// use AlamorefireImage UIImage extension to resize UIImage
let scaledImage = image.af_imageScaled(to: size)
// render
imageView.image = scaledImage
```

Or just I render image to screen directly

```
imageView.frame.size = CGRect(width: 100, height: 100)
imageView.image =image
```

Which is better drawing performance?

Comment: Did you do any benchmarking on your own?

Comment: I'm assuming `image.af_imageScaled(to: size)` actually scales the image to `100 x 100` *pixels*. On screen, however, a `UIImageVIew` at `100 x 100` will want an image of `100 x100` only on really old devices. Otherwise, it will want either a `300 x 300` image (for iPhone X, iPhone 8 Plus, iPhone 7 Plus, and iPhone 6s Plus) or a `200 x 200` image for all other devices. Scaling it down to `100 x 100` will almost certainly give you unsatisfactory resolutions (blurry images).

Comment: use aspect fill property with clipstobound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider the next cases:

1. If you are using an **image from the bundle** (project folder).
   The best way is to use Asset Catalog. In this case, you have to store the image with exact size you need, eg. 100x100 pt (specific image for specific screen size, eg. 100x100 for 1x, 200x200 for 2x and 300x300 for 3x). This is the best option for performance.
2. In case you are **downloading images from the network**. I suppose the best way is to have one thumbnail image on the server and large image. Eg. thumbnail image with size 100x100 px for small user photo in a list and 500x500 px for large user photo on the user profile page.
3. There is some situation when you **downloading from the network an image with large size only** eg. 2000x2000. In this situation, you can resize an image before the render, like you propose. But do it not on the main thread to prevent app freeze. If this image will be used many times in the app (eg. in the table view cell) you can even save this rescaled image to the cache and use it from the cache next time.